# Creating Immutable Classes with Multiple Constructors

Tags: java, immutability

I'm reading [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html) on creating immutable classes in Java, and decided to modify a class I was writing to the specifications outlined on the page.

```
final String personfirstname;
final String personlastname;
final int personAge;

public Person(String firstname, String lastname) {

   this.personfirstname = firstname;
   this.personlastname = lastname;
}

public Person(String firstname, String lastname, int personAge){
    this(firstname,lastname);

    this.personAge = personAge;
}
```

My issue is, eclipse says that the `personAge` may not have been set, despite the fact that I'm doing so in the second constructor. Is it not possible to create an immutable class with two constructors in java? If it's possible how would I do it?

This closest I've come is this:

```
final private String personfirstname;
final private String personlastname;
final private int personAge;

public Person(String firstname, String lastname) {

    this.personfirstname = firstname;
    this.personlastname = lastname;
    //Set a default age
    this.personAge = 0;

}

public Person(String firstname, String lastname, int age){

    this.personfirstname = firstname;
    this.personlastname = lastname;
    this.personAge=age;
}
```

I provided a default age, **BUT** my constructors aren't chained, is this okay? If not, how would I provide two constructors in an immutable class?

Comment: So, if someone invokes the first constructor what is the value of `personage`?

Comment: @Jim Garrison - Check my update

Answer (score 5):

A user can call the first constructor, which doesn't set `personAge` at all.  The `final` variable must be definitely assigned by the end of the constructor, and it isn't.

Switch the assignments of `personfirstname` and `personlastname` in one constructor with the call to the `this` constructor in the other.  This way, the first constructor delegates to the second constructor to do everything, including setting the age.

```
public Person(String firstname, String lastname) {
    // or another reasonable default value for age
    this(firstname, lastname, 0);  
}

public Person(String firstname, String lastname, int personAge){
    this.personfirstname = firstname;
    this.personlastname = lastname;
    this.personAge = personAge;
}
```

The constructors remain chained, so no code is duplicated.  All fields are assigned together, and all fields are definitely assigned at the end of a call to any constructor.

Comment: @rgettman- Thanks, I updated my question, is it okay if they're not chained, as I did in my updated example?

Comment: It is ok for your example that they aren't chained.  The code that is duplicated is minimal.  But in general, with more fields and/or more complicated logic, chaining is the way to go to prevent code duplication.

Comment: It is OK, but you are duplicating code. In a more complex class, this introduces the potential for bugs.

Comment: @rgettman - Many thanks, bare with me I'm learning, but when chaining constructors, what is the proper practice, chain the constructor with the most arguments to the one with lesser arguments? Most examples I've seen do this, is it wrong to do it the other way, chaining the constructor with less arguments to the one with more(providing default values for empty arguments)?

Comment: I think that the best practice when chaining constructors is to call the constructor with more arguments from the one with less arguments, providing default values.  This organizes all of the assignment statements in one place -- the constructor with the most arguments.  Additionally, with more arguments and more possibilities of optional arguments, it is wise to switch to [the Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern#Java_Example).  The Builder class accumulates all arguments, validates them, and then calls one constructor on the main class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either call the second Person(first, last, age) constructor inside your first constructor, or you need to set this.personAge to some default value inside your first constructor.

As of now if someone were to declare a Person using the first constructor, then the final int personAge would not have a value.