# Deafult Value for Custom Object in Chained Constructor

Tags: c#, constructor

I was [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35326306/creating-immutable-classes-with-multiple-constructors) about constructor chaining and I was wondering, if one has a sub instance object inside a class, take for example below, the Course class, how should it be instantiated with the professor object?

```
public Course(string courseCode, string courseTitle, Professor teacher)
{
    if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(courseCode))
    {
      throw new ArgumentNullException("Course Code Cannot Be Empty");
    }  

    this.courseCode = courseCode;

    if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(courseTitle))
    {
      throw new ArgumentNullException("Course Title Cannot Be Empty");
    }
    this.courseTitle = courseTitle;

       this.prof = Professor.Clone(teacher);
 }

 public Course(string courseCode, string courseTitle)
        :this(courseCode,courseTitle,new Professor())
 {


 }

Professor class:

 public int id {get; private set; }
 public string firstName{get; private set;}
 public string lastName {get; private set;}

 public Professor(int ID, string firstName, string lastname)
 {
      this.id = ID;

      if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstName))
      {
          throw new ArgumentNullException("first name Cannot be Null");
      }

      this.firstName = firstName;

      if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lastname))
      {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("last name cannot be null");
      }
      this.lastName = lastname;
  }
```

The comment in the linked question suggested this:

> I think that the best practice when chaining constructors is to call
>   the constructor with more arguments from the one with less arguments,
>   providing default values.

My `Course` class has a `professor` object as one of the arguments. What should my default values for professor be if the user were to create a course that doesn't have a professor?

Comment: This should probably be marked for closure as this is EXTREMELY situational and invokes a whole firestorm of opinions.  But I'll start the firestorm with my own opinion: You should not default the professor as it is a dependency of the `Course`, you cannot have a class with a "default professor" -- who is the default professor?

Comment: It depends on what you need, sometimes you can call constructor with less parameters (form one that have more), and then perform certain operations in constructor body with rest of the parameters.

Comment: @CodingGorilla - So what should I put as a default professor if none is provided?

Comment: `"a course that doesn't have a professor"` - Then, well, `null`.  If there is no professor, then `null` literally means "no value here".

Comment: The Professor class can't be null though

Comment: @Svetlana You shouldn't (again this is my opinion), whoever is trying to construct a class should be required to provide a valid professor as it makes no sense to see a class listing like: "C# Programming 101 - Default Professor".

Comment: @Svetlana: Then the constructor should require one.  You either need to have a value or you don't.  You can't have it both ways.  Before worrying about the technical implementation, consider the real-world semantics of what you're trying to represent in the code.  Can you have a class without a professor?  If so, then `Professor` is either `null` or some default placeholder object.  If not, then require a valid `Professor`.

Comment: @David - Think you nailed it. I was thinking exactly that, but I wanted to ask to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If a `Professor` cannot exist without a name or ID, then I would simply not have an overloaded constructor in `Course` that creates a default professor.** You would manage a `Course` instance with a `null` Professor as needed.

---

If they can, and you want a generic professor "John Smith" then I would let the `Professor` class specify what an "empty" professor means (although I would not recommend this):

```
public class Professor
{
    ...

    private static Professor _default;
    public static Professor Default
    {
        get
        {
            if (_default == null)
                _default = new Professor(-1, "John", "Smith");
            return _default;
        }
    }
}
```

And then change your overloaded constructor in `Course` to:

```
public Course (string courseCode, string courseTitle)
    : this(courseCode, courseTitle, Professor.Default)
```

This separate of duties will keep your code a little more maintainable, and the singleton instance of a default professor will allow you to do things later like:

```
if (myProfInstance == Professor.Default)
    // insert into DB, for example
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public Course(string courseCode, string courseTitle)
        :this(courseCode,courseTitle,new Professor())
 {

 }
```

in this you shouldnot instantiate new professor() as you dont have any professor.

```
public Course(string courseCode, string courseTitle)
        :this(courseCode,courseTitle,null)
 {

 }
```

use this constructor when you want to create course with no professor and assign the professor object only if it is not null in the other constructor.

Comment: Professor cannot be null

Comment: @Svetlana So why have a constructor that doesn't have a `Professor` parameter?  If `Professor` is required then it needs to be a constructor parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> What should my default values for professor be if the user were to create a course that doesn't have a professor?

The design approach should provided that answer to what a *default* professor is when one cannot be directly associated. Otherwise as a developer you need to create that *default* professor which is simply a bare minimum informational instance which can be handled and updated in future processing in the system.

---

The idea behind constructor chaining is to simply to organize overloaded constructors to *centralize* common instantiation actions so they are not repeated.

Comment: This is more along the lines of what I was think, just asked to be sure. So I can provide a default value for professor, as you say one that cannot be directly associated.